# VolumeMount Name not found

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have below StatefulSet postgres for EKS. When I run it I am getting below error.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age               From                    Message
  ----     ------        ----              ----                    -------
   Warning  FailedCreate  7s (x17 over 1m)  statefulset-controller  create Pod postgres-0 in StatefulSet postgres failed error: Pod "postgres-0" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "postgredb"
```

StatefulSet:

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: StatefulSet
  metadata:
    name: postgres
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: postgres # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
    serviceName: "postgres"
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: postgres
      spec:
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
        containers:
          - name: postgres
            image: postgres:10.4
            imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
            ports:
              - containerPort: 5432
            volumeMounts:
              - name: postgredb
                mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: postgresdb
          annotations:
            volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "aws-efs"
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
```

I have StorageClass configured as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typo.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: postgredb
```

It should be `name:postgresdb`, not `name:postgredb`.